# CREATE TABLE TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY] is redundant it there's only one filegroup?

Tags: filegroups

I've recently generated scripts for a legacy database, and discovered that most of the tables were created with `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]`, but there's only one filegroup.

`TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` is redundant when there is only a single filegroup, correct?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, this is redundant. By default, SSMS will script these

The option is here:

[image: SSMS File group option]

Answer (score 2):

This is a also a long standing bug because it also generates TEXTIMAGE_ON when running the script fails because that option is set when no appropriate text columns!