# TEXTIMAGE_ON and Computed geography column

Tags: sql-server, spatial

There is an unusual behavior I need help understanding. Using SQL Server 2019 Express (v15.0.2080.9) and Management Studio.

Here is the test I'm running:

1. Create a table with a geography column. This will create the table with Text filegroup PRIMARY (by default)

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestTable]
(
     [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
     [Latitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
     [Longitude] [decimal](9, 6) NULL,
     [GeoLocation] [geography]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

2. Using Management Studio, generate a CREATE script of that table. The `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` will be added, since the table has a geography column
3. Drop the geography column

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] 
    DROP COLUMN [GeoLocation]
```

4. Add another column, but this time as a Computed column that uses lat/long to calculate a point. The column type will be inferred as geography

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TestTable] 
    ADD [GeoLocation] AS (CASE 
                              WHEN [Latitude] IS NOT NULL AND [Longitude] IS NOT NULL 
                                  THEN [geography]::Point([Latitude], [Longitude], (4236))
                          END) PERSISTED
GO
```

5. Generate the CREATE script again for that table. It will still be generated as `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]`
6. Change the table name in the script for something else (like TestTable2) and try running the script. It will fail with the following message:

> Msg 1709, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Cannot use TEXTIMAGE_ON when a table has no text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), non-FILESTREAM varbinary(max), xml or large CLR type columns.

7. Remove the `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` from the creation script and run it again. TestTable2 will be created successfully
8. Generate the CREATE script again for the TestTable2. This time, `TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]` won't be generated

I don't understand why step 6 failed, since we do have a geography column (it's computed, but it's persisted). Shouldn't it be possible to specify the `TEXTIMAGE_ON filegroup` for a computed column with geography type inferred?

Answer (score 0):

I just had a similar situation, you did the right thing and it is working.

For more information have a look [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/162337/22336) and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/190779/22336).